# Scrapy bot crawling website outside given domain without any context

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider running on a single website and the domain is

```
allowed_domains = ['eaton.com']
 start_urls = ['https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us.html']
```

However during scraping it is also scraping websites outside the given domain for which the log looks like this

```
2021-01-13 13:11:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cyh.com.cn/> (referer: None)
```

I am not able to understand why it would scrape a website where nothing from the allowed website matches and the logs show that there was no redirect or reference. Please help me to make sense of this issue and any solution is most welcome.

**Update#1**

As suggested by @Georgiy I am attaching the settings from the log

```
2021-01-13 12:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: smartspider)
2021-01-13 12:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-01-13 12:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-01-13 12:40:58 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'smartspider',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 2,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 30,
 'LOG_FILE': 'log.txt',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'smartspider.spiders',
 'RETRY_TIMES': 5,
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['smartspider.spiders'],
 'TELNETCONSOLE_PASSWORD': 'scrapy',
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}
2021-01-13 12:40:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-01-13 12:40:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'smartspider.middlewares.FilterResponses',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'smartspider.middlewares.RandomProxyForReDirectedUrls',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-01-13 12:40:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-01-13 12:40:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
```

Please let me know what might be the root cause

Comment: It is required to provide more data from log output. Especially following first lines of log data: `INFO[scrapy.utils.log]Scrapy version..`, `INFO[scrapy.utils.log] Versions:...`,`INFO[scrapy.crawler] Overridden settings:..`,`INFO [scrapy.middleware] Enabled spider middlewares:`

Comment: @Georgiy : I have updated the logs

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself. If you are using `dont_filter`, that could cause `allowed_domains` to be ignored.